# JSON on paper + password - how to access account?

Tags: wallets

When I created wallet on myetherwallet, I couldn't download the JSON file from unknown reason, so I just did the printscreen. Now, I'm stuck with the paper data of the json file (with encrypted private key) and the password for my wallet that I know.

How do I access the wallet with what I have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "access", you mean "send transactions from". If you only mean "view account balance", you can type the public address into a block explorer like https://etherscan.io.

First, you type out the contents of the screenshot you took and save it in a plain text file (using something like Notepad on Windows or TextEdit.app on a Mac -- not using a word processor like Word or Pages). Then, in myetherwallet, use the menu item "Send Ether & Tokens", select Keystore File as the option, click "Select Wallet File..." and select your newly created plain text file. It'll ask you for your password. Enter that. And then you're off to the races.

Comment: Tnx a lot! It recognized the file but I got the following message> Error: Key derivation failed - possibly wrong passphrase. Can it be something else except the password, since Im sure about it?

Comment: Did you enter everything into the text file exactly as shown? For example, if you wrote an `l` instead of a `1` or an `r` instead of `R`, the file format would still be correct, but would result in an error like you saw.

Comment: I'll check once again. To make sure I kept the formating, I made a new wallet, downloaded json file and then copy/pasted data from my old wallet into the new json file. Tnx again for your help!